# How to make Nginx serve a default object

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have a fresh nginx install on an Amazon EC2 micro instance.

It is working well and serves content as intended when I specify:

`http://32.32.32.32/index.php`

however, when I specify the URL as:
`http://32.32.32.32` I get a 403 forbidden error.

What I would like to happen is when the user specifies `http://32.32.32.32` I would like `index.php` to be served automatically.

`http://32.32.32.32` === serves by default ===> `http://32.32.32.32/index.php`

I know the location of the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. I presume the modifications will occur here if possible. Thanks to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

Nginx has option "index" for that, in your case you need something like this

```
server {
...
index index.html index.php /index.php;
...
}
```